# PHP setcookie for the entire domain name

Tags: php, setcookie

I use this function to set a cookie for the entire domain name:

```
setcookie("tuittingID", $random, mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015), '/', '.domainname.com');
```

The problem now is that I do not know what `domainname.com` will be, since this script will be used by different people on different domain names.

I have top find a way to do the same thing but without having the client editing that line.

Is there a way?

Let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `$_SERVER` superglobal. It contains various parts of the address (for instance in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`), although you may still need to do some cutting yourself. You can explode the hostname into an array, using the `.`. as a separator. Combining the last two items, you get the domain name (SLD + TLD).

If this code is to be used as a library, I would offer the user (of the library) the possibility to use the full domain, only the second level domain, or a custom setting.

Comment: This becomes a pain to automate for domains like `foo.co.uk`.

Comment: Yes it does. You can create a list of exceptions (TLDs with fixed SLDs) if you like, but it is always a good thing to make it customizable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this to set domain name:

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, preg_replace('/www/','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("tuittingID", $random, mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, ".".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`